# What features cause Head Movement?

Tags: syntax, reference-request, minimalism, movement

Suppose a head, T, moves to C. In the minimalist program, what features cause the movement of that head? I've been looking at literature on head movement but all I can find is papers on arguments for and against head movement and what head movement really is, nothing about the features that drive it.

Can you guys give me some sources?

Comment: In Baker's theory the Morphological Visibility Condition is driving incorporation, but this doesn't cover all cases of head movement, of course, and certainly not T-to-C.

Comment: @Nephenee, have you read Pesetsky and Torrego 2000? It's classic.